# Sql for generating previous and next links in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

This has me completely stumped. From a set of numbers - for this example 1 to 20, I'm trying to do previous and next links, so they end up like this: I'll be supplying the number to start from.

```
1       6           11          16
2       7           12          17
3       8           13          18
4       9           14          19
5       10          15          20
n-5    p-6 n-10   p-11 n-15    p-16
```

Have you any idea how to do the sql for something like this?

I was trying to build on this one, but no luck:

```
SELECT c.id,
  (SELECT MAX(p.id) FROM mytable p WHERE p.id < c.id AND p.country = 'us') prev_id,
  (SELECT MIN(n.id) FROM mytable n WHERE n.id > c.id AND n.country = 'us') next_id
FROM mytable as c WHERE c.id = 5;
```

**Table data**

```
    "id"    "country"
"1"     "US"
"2"     "US"
"3"     "US"
"4"     "US"
"5"     "US"
"6"     "US"
"7"     "US"
"8"     "US"
"9"     "US"
"10"    "US"
"11"    "US"
"12"    "US"
```

**Desired output**

number provided by me = 10

```
prev  | next
-------------
6     | 10
```

Comment: Post the schema (field structure) of `MyTable`.

Comment: It's simple. I posted it. I'm using this for testing.

Comment: And what is the requirement. To print `ID`s in `4` columns?

Comment: Not 4 columns. One one column. If I gave you No. 10, the previous would be 6 and next would be 10. See p-6 n-10 in my example.

Comment: Can you please provide the desired output based on your sample data (you already posted)?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37834/discussion-between-pm-77-1-and-jmenezes)

Comment: Why are you still using mysql??  This can be easily handled with PostgreSQL's [window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html) and is certainly more efficient.

Comment: @vol7ron Not many hosts offer PostgreSql

Comment: @jmenezes you mean not many free hosts :) many of the paid ones will install it; even some of the free ones if you can contact them, but you're right it's generally not part of the LAMP installs.  MySQL isn't horrible, but if you have a choice, try and get off the MySQL train.

Comment: @vol7ron I meant paid ones. I've never used free ones till now. Can you recommend any? I'm jasonmzs@gmail.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is `MySQL` solution:

```
SET @number=15;
SET @counter=0;


SELECT x.id, @number as next
FROM (
SELECT id, (@counter:=@counter+1) as line FROM TableData WHERE id <=@number ORDER BY id 
) x
WHERE x.line = @counter-5;
```

`number` is what you specify.

You can see how it works in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2b649/1).  Feel free to change its data and test,

Comment: Right. Thanks a lot for this. I tested here and it seems to be working nicely.

Comment: Link now works. I added 'CA' (not 'US') record and removed some lines so IDs are not sequential.

Comment: Your solution works fantastic. Thanks very much for helping on this. BTW, is that really you in your avatar image?

Comment: No, it's not me. Got this image from internet.